# WKWebView no muestra nada

Tags: web, swift

Estoy haciendo un programa que muestre una documento html. Trabajo con MacOsx y swift 5. El código que tengo es:

```swift
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var vista: NSView!
    @IBOutlet var vistaWeb: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let frame = NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 440, height: 230)
        vistaWeb = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
        vistaWeb.uiDelegate = self
        
        let htmlStr = "<html>Hola Mundo!</html>"
        vistaWeb.loadHTMLString(htmlStr, baseURL: nil)
        
        print("Fin")
    }
}
```

En la escena principal del storyboard he puesto un WKWebView con un IBOutlet de nombre "vistaWeb".

En el WKWebView no sale nada.

También he probado con una página web, cambiando las dos lineas anteriores a print("Fin") con:

```
    let myUrl = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
    vistaWeb.load(myRequest)
```

y sigue igual.

Alguién sabe qué estoy haciendo mal.

Saludos de Víctor.-

Comment: Por qué creas nuevamente una instancia de `WKWebView`? Utiliza la del IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

para que tu aplicación MacOsx pueda tener conexión a internet y hacer requests necesitas habilitarlo desde la configuración de tu proyecto.

Selecciona tu archivo `.xcodeproj` dirígete a la opción *Signing & Capabilities*, dentro de la sección *App Sandbox* estará el apartado de *Networking*, una vez ahí seleccionas **Outgoing Connections (Client)** y listo!

[image: Como habilitar conexión a internet]

Activando esa opción deberías poder visualizar el contenido de tu WebView, un saludo.

**UPDATE**

Este es el código que usé, en el storyboard agregué un `WKWebView` y mediante el outlet cargue la web.

```swift
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya estaba hecho. Sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @VíctorRodríguezMartín he actualizado mi respuesta agregando el código fuente que usé.

Answer (score 0):

He probado este código para ios:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Private
    private var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Web view
        let webViewPrefs = WKPreferences()
        webViewPrefs.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewPrefs.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        
        let webViewConf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webViewConf.preferences = webViewPrefs
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewConf)
        
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        view.addSubview(webView)
        
        load(url: "https://www.google.com")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private methods
    private func load(url: String) {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!))
    }
}
```

He eliminado outlets a botones y otras cosas.

El código funciona y abre la página indicada.

Luego he adaptado el código para macOS:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Private
    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Web view
        let webViewPrefs = WKPreferences()
        webViewPrefs.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewPrefs.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        
        let webViewConf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webViewConf.preferences = webViewPrefs
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewConf)
        
        print(view.frame)
        
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.width,.height]
        
        view.addSubview(webView)
        
        load(url: "https://www.google.com")
    }
    
    private func load(url: String) {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!))
    }
}
```

No da errores pero no se muestra nada.

¡¡Estoy confuso!!

Saludos de Víctor.-

Comment: Esta es una respuesta?